# Iterate over ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax response and I would like to iterate over it pulling out the data required. At the moment, I have the values from the first result being displayed on the page in an input box but I do not know how to display the other results, creating a list.

This is my ajax request which is correctly displaying the results from the first record:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "messageAPI",
    method: "get",
    type: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);

        let message = result["Data"]["dsMessage"]["ttMessage"][0];
        $(".reference").val(message.reference);
        $(".date").val(message.date);

    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }

});
```

This is how I am currently displaying the data on the page:

```
<input class="date" />
```

This is a shortened version of my JSON file:

```
{"Data":{"dsMessage":{"ttMessage":
[
{"date":"2018-02-09","reference":"Call Mr Jones ",0},
{"date":"2018-03-08","reference":"Call Mr Smith ",0},
]
}}}
```

I have been searching online and from what I have read the for loop should go in the success function but I am not sure how to construct it. I have tried some that I have found online but they haven't worked.

I tried this piece of code but it not produce any results or errors:

```
 $.each(Message.items, function (index, Message) {
                    alert(Message.reference)
                });
```

I'm at a bit of a loss and as I am not experienced I do not know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your JSON like this:

```
{"Data":{"dsMessage":{"ttMessage":
[
{"date":"2018-02-09","reference":"Call Mr Jones ", "index": 0},
{"date":"2018-03-08","reference":"Call Mr Smith ", "index": 0}
]
}}}
```

Note the `"index":` that comes before each zero. Also removed a trailing comma in the array, but that may or may not give you trouble.

At that point, I iterated it like this:

```js
for (var m = 0; m < result["Data"]["dsMessage"]["ttMessage"].length; m ++) {
    var message = result["Data"]["dsMessage"]["ttMessage"][m];
    console.log(message.reference); // do what you want with this
    console.log(message.date); // and this
}
```

Comment: `"index"` is possibly a poor member name for the `0` values in the array. But, since I'm not sure what they represent, I added them as examples. The problem is that each item in an object is a name/value pair. As the JSON was originally provided, the `0` values have no names.

Comment: Thanks so much Mark! Your code has allowed me to iterate each record in the console, so that's a big step forward for me. I will now try to work out how to display them in an unordered list and also limit the number of results shown. Very much appreciate your help :-)

Comment: You betcha. Extra credit: since you know the name of the members in your object traversal, you could replace `result["Data"]["dsMessage"]["ttMessage"]` with `result.Data.dsMessage.ttMessage` for easier readability (and less typing).

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I'm just starting out and trying to learn so these tips are really helpful. I managed to get the results in a ul, now to limit them. Thanks again, your kindness has made my day!